# Porque No me cargan los datos de la tabla en los QLineEdit?

Tags: c++, qt

```
 connect(tableView,SIGNAL (clicked()), this, SLOT(on_tableView_clicked(QModelIndex &index)));

void MainWindow::on_tableView_clicked(QModelIndex &index)
    {
        if(!index.isValid()){
            return;
        }

        QString id=mModel->data(mModel->index(index.row(),0)).toString();

        QSqlQuery q;
        q.exec(QString("SELECT id_elemento,id_grupo,id_tipo,nombre,descripcion,icono FROM elemento WHERE id_elemento= " + id +";"));
        q.first();
        QPixmap pixmap;
        if(!pixmap.loadFromData(q.value(5).toByteArray())){
            labelImg->setText("<b>Error de Imagen</b>");
            return;
        }

        lineCod->setText(q.value(0).toString());
        lineGroup->setText(q.value(1).toString());
        lineType->setText(q.value(2).toString());
        lineName->setText(q.value(3).toString());
        textDescription->setPlainText(q.value(4).toString());
        labelImg->setPixmap(pixmap);
    }
```

Resultado cuando cliqueo en la tabla

QSqlQuery::value: not positioned on a valid record
QSqlQuery::value: not positioned on a valid record
QSqlQuery::value: not positioned on a valid record
QSqlQuery::value: not positioned on a valid record
QSqlQuery::value: not positioned on a valid record
QSqlQuery::value: not positioned on a valid record
QSqlQuery::value: not positioned on a valid record

Comment: ¿Has probado la query fuera del código a ver si en la Base de Datos te funciona?

Comment: la query funciona correctamente, lo que puede estar mal es el valor de id, pero la query esta bien.

Comment: Así pues, la query devuelve resultados. ¿Podrías editar tu pregunta con los resultados que recibes?

Comment: connect(tableView,SIGNAL (clicked()), this, SLOT (on_tableView_clicked(QModelIndex &index)));

Comment: Y me devuelve esto por consola Starting D:\Documents\signalDB\build-signalDB-C_Qt_4_8_0-Debug\debug\signalDB.exe...
Object::connect: No such signal QTableView::clicked() in ..\signal_dev\mainwindow.cpp:236
Object::connect:  (sender name:   'tableView')

Comment: ¿Podrías **editar** tu **pregunta** con los resultados que recibes?

Answer (score 0):

Con esta línea de código solucioné mi problema:

```
connect(tableView,SIGNAL (clicked(const QModelIndex &)), this, SLOT (on_tableView_clicked(const QModelIndex &)));
```

Comment: Te recomiendo usar el nuevo estilo de conección: `connect(tableView, &QTableView::clicked, this, &MainWindow::on_tableView_clicked);`